# "Wall" but send text to local terminal, too?

Tags: terminal, broadcast, wall

I have tried `wall`, but it does not show the message to local terminal. Can I show it to local terminal, too? The remote SSH and the local GUI terminal are the same user account.

The reason why I am trying to do is that I want to use it basically for "copy and paste" between host and guest (VM), when the hypervisor's "copy and paste" feature is not working. I could save the text to a text file and then reload it on the guest, but just displaying the text like `wall` would be easier.

Comment: The commands `wall` and `write` rely on the `utmp` records. Not every terminal emulator updates these records, in some it's a config option, while some others don't support updating these records at all (you might launch an external helper utility to maintain these records).

Answer (score 0):

`wall` is a message broadcast facility for the local machine on which it's run. There is no capability for sending messages to remote systems. (See `man wall` for further information.)

If you're logged in from to a remote system with something like `ssh`, and `wall` is run on that remote system, the message will be displayed on all logged-in terminals. This will include the one hosting your `ssh` session.

Note that unless you a superuser, you can only write to terminals owned by other users where the user has not used `mesg n` (a default in a number of distributions' `.profile` files). The superuser can write everywhere regardless, and a user can always write to terminals logged in with their own user account.

If you're trying to send messages between two of your own terminals you might find `write` a little more focussed (see `man write`):

```
write roaima
....
[Ctrl/D]
```

Or, for specific direction to the user `roaima` logged on to terminal `/dev/pts/0`:

```
write roaima pts/0
....
[Ctrl/D]
```

Some systems also include `talk`, `xtalk`, [`ytalk`](https://ytalk.ourproject.org/), `phone`, or one of a [similar slew](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52735/100397) of applications. If these are installed on directly reachable systems it is possible to connect sessions across the network. (Note that I haven't tried these in well over ten years so they may be seriously obsolete.)

Comment: By "GUI terminal" I meant the default terminal app running in the guest OS's desktop.  Wall, write, and other things I have tried only works in GUI terminal --> SSH but not in the other direction. For example, it seems that the SSH window running on the host is pts/0. In the GUI terminal, if I do `write myid pts/1`, the SSH window says broadcast from pts/0, and message can be sent. But if I do `write myid pts/0' in the SSH window, it says that the account is not logged in on pts/0.

Comment: You probably aren't logged on to `pts/0`. You can find out what tty you're on with the `tty` command

Comment: See my comment to the main post about `utmp` records. That's why `write` might fail with an error message for you. If you want to send a message to one of your own terminals, you might just do `echo message > /dev/pts/0` or alike.